# Which sorting algorithm is used by .net in IComparer

Tags: .net, algorithm, sorting

Do any one know which sorting algorithm is used by .net when we implement `IComparer` in our class?

Comment: [This has changed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc(v=vs.100).aspx) since .NET 4.5: Now Insertion sort for n<16, otherwise starts with Quicksort and switches to Heapsort when the number of partitions (recursion depth?) exceeds 2 * Log^N. Called: [Introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort)

Comment: @Laoujin And which algorithm is used by `Enumerable.OrderBy`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2792159/540352

Answer (score 10):

[QuickSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickSort) seems to be it.

The documentation on [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx) says

> This interface is used in conjunction with the [Array.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort.aspx) and [Array.BinarySearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.binarysearch.aspx) methods.

The [Array.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aw9s5t8f.aspx) documentation says

> This method uses the QuickSort algorithm. This implementation performs an unstable sort; that is, if two elements are equal, their order might not be preserved. In contrast, a stable sort preserves the order of elements that are equal.

Answer (score 8):

The [current documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.7.1) says it uses a type of **[Introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort)**, a hybrid sorting algoritm:

Is works like this:

1. If the partition size is fewer than 16 elements, it uses an
   **insertion sort** algorithm
2. If the number of partitions exceeds 2 * LogN, where N is the range
   of    the input array, it uses a **Heapsort** algorithm.
3. Otherwise, it uses a **Quicksort** algorithm.

   [source here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.7.1)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aw9s5t8f%28VS.80%29.aspx), .NET uses QuickSort. By the way, the method absolutely doesn't depend on the comparer (as long as it's comparison-based), why should .NET therefore use a different method depending on whether you provide a custom comparer or not?